# FFmpeg hardcoded subtitles revert to default font if subtitle is html

Tags: ffmpeg

Here's how I'm using `ffmpeg` to hardcode the subtitles:

```
ffmpeg -i tmp/input.mp4 -vf "subtitles=tmp/input.mp4:force_style='OutlineColour=&H80000000,BorderStyle=3,Outline=1,Shadow=0,MarginV=20,Fontname=Liberation Mono'" -avoid_negative_ts make_zero tmp/output.mp4
```

which works fine if the subtitle is plain text but if it has `html` tags in it, then it reverts back to using system's default font. `<i> hello </i>` for example causes problem.

I've tried cleaning up html tags and then using `-vf "subtitles=cleanedsubs.srt:..."` but it doesn't work even on plain texts.

How can I force same font even on italic / bold / any other forms?

**Extra info**

Running:

```
ffmpeg -i tmp/input.mp4 -filter_complex "subtitles=tmp/input.mp4:force_style='fontname=Liberation Mono'" -f null -
```

Shows:

```
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x55ad579abd00] Using font provider fontconfig
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (h264) -> subtitles (graph 0)
  subtitles (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (wrapped_avframe)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x55ad579aa3c0] Shaper: FriBidi 0.19.7 (SIMPLE) HarfBuzz-ng 1.7.2 (COMPLEX)
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x55ad579aa3c0] Using font provider fontconfig
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x55ad579aa3c0] fontselect: (Liberation Mono, 400, 0) -> /usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation/LiberationMono-Regular.ttf, 0, LiberationMono
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x55ad579aa3c0] fontselect: (Liberation Mono, 400, 100) -> /usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation/LiberationMono-Italic.ttf, 0, LiberationMono-Italic
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x55ad579aa3c0] fontselect: (Serif, 400, 100) -> /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf, 0, DejaVuSerif-Italic
                                                    ↑                                  
                                                 problem
```

Comment: @llogan pasted it here for you. https://shrib.com/#4Ob98Ubhyox1j-Re0aOw

Comment: this in unclean version btw, did you want cleaned one?

Comment: Yes, I have `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation2/LiberationMono-Italic.ttf: Liberation Mono:style=Italic` if I do `fc-list`

Comment: @llogan https://shrib.com/#nFdK5.1WnlQDQ82sS0Z-

Comment: Yes, yours look correct. What should I do?

Comment: I removed ffmpeg and am now installing using snap, though my connection is a bit slow. Can I have the full command you used to produced the video you sent so I can try?

Comment: I re-installed using snap but it's still not working in my own use case. However I can reproduce the same output as yours using your command.

Comment: I thought `tmp/input.mp4` was a typo for a SRT file. Didn't realize you were feeding mov_text to subtitles filter. Give it the subs from `media/file.mkv` instead: `ffmpeg -ss $1 -t $2 -i media/file.mkv -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v -map 0:s:6 -c:s mov_text -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -vf "subtitles=tmp/file.mkv:stream_index=6:force_style='OutlineColour=&H80000000,BorderStyle=3,Outline=1,Shadow=0,MarginV=20,Fontname=Liberation Mono'" tmp/input.mp4`

Comment: @llogan I used your command and supplied the original mkv file `media/file.mkv` as subtitles but no subtitle is hardcoded. nothing shows up.

Comment: + I edited my post and added the log of `fontselect` which shows it eventually chooses `DejaVu Serif`

Answer (score 0):

Possible bug when feeding mov_text to subtitles filter. I can reproduce the issue in git master branch. I did not investigate further.

Workaround is to provide the subtitles filter the SRT subtitle stream present in your original MKV input (`file.mkv`):

```
ffmpeg -i file.mkv -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -vf "subtitles=file.mkv:stream_index=6:force_style='OutlineColour=&H80000000,BorderStyle=3,Outline=1,Shadow=0,MarginV=20,Fontname=Liberation Mono'" output.mp4
```

Make sure `stream_index` is referencing the desired subtitle stream. See [subtitles filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) documentation.